# What is an IBM MQ stanza?

Tags: ibm-mq

The documentation refers to [configuring information with stanzas](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.con.doc/q123890_.htm), but what is a stanza?

Is it just a fancy name for a sub-section of configuration?

Comment: Yes, it's name given to section of related properties. See Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanza_(computing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, in this context a stanza refers to a sub-section of a IBM MQ configuration file.

For example MQ clients come by default with a config file called `mqclient.ini`, in this file you may see something like the following:

```
TCP:
   ClntSndBuffSize=0
```

In this example the *stanza* is `TCP` and it has a single *attribute* `ClntSndBuffSize` set to the value `0`.